# How to set location in map in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, mapkit

I am trying to learn MAP for iPhone.

What I have right now is below.

1. Created new project
2. Added framework for MAP
3. Brought map object on storyboard (UIViewController)
4. Run the project.

What I see is, its not showing any location. When I change location in xcode, it shows me the dot at location.

What I wanted is, by default it should show me the PIN to the location that I will set by using latitude and longitude. Also the map should be zoomed. What I meant by zoom is, I should see the location with lets say 13 zoom effect. Right now, I see world map on screen.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Check if in Interface Builder you created the viewController for iPhone 4.0 inch (iPhone 5) and you are running the app inside a iPhone 3.5 inch screen (retina or not retina)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating an application with Map you need to implement the `MKAnnotation`, `MKMapViewDelegate` delgates.

This is a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial) for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can center your map around a location by doing something like this:

```
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
    mapRegion.center.latitude = aLatitude;
    mapRegion.center.longitude = aLongitude;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
    self.mapView.region = mapRegion;
```

Use the span values to determine the zoom level you want.

In order to show a pin you need to create an annotation with the coordinates of your location and then add it to the map.

Also, check out this tutorial.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Dot is showing your current location.

If you want to add a pin with coordinate you should call `addAnnotation` method with object which conforms to `MKAnnotation` protocol. Such object has a property `coordinate` (you should add it to your class):

```objective-c
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

Also you should add `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol to your controller and implement `-mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method. It works as `-tableView:viewForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```objective-c
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"annotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];   // Reusing

    if (!annotationView) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

        annotationView = pinView;
    }
    else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation; // Reusing already created pin as UITableViewCell does
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

Then when you call

```objective-c
MKMapView *mapView = ...;
id<MKAnnotation> obj = ...;
[mapView addAnnotation:obj];
```

The pin would be placed on map.

For zoom look [there](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/). There is a handy category for those purposes.

If you want to remove current location dot you should find an object with class `MKUserLocation` in `mapView.annotations` and then call `[mapView removeAnnotation:userLocationDot]`.